# Taking values out from a dictionary and storing it in a variable

Tags: python

What am I doing wrong here? I am getting errors when I run it. It says I can't convert string type to float. I want to store the values from C1 to c1 variables as float type for calculations.

```
import csv

file = open('Items.csv')
reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
items = dict()
headersRead = False
headers = []

for row in reader:
    if headersRead == False:
        for i in range(len(row)):
            items[row[i]] = []
            print(row[i])

        headers = row
        print(headers)
        headersRead = True

    else:
        for i in range(len(row)):
            items[headers[i]].append(row[i])

for key in items:
    c1 = float(items[key][0])
    c2 = float(items[key][1])
    c3 = float(items[key][2])
    constant = float(items[key][3])

file.close()
```

This is the csv file I am working with.

```
Item,C1,C2,C3,Constant
Guitar Hero,-0.1111,0,-0.2,10
iPhone 7,-0.1,-0.2,-0.33333,3
iPhone SE,-0.889,-0.23,-0.5,2
Star Wars,-0.0778,-0.373333333,-0.5,4
Markers,-0.667,-0.488333333,-0.65,3
Avengers,-0.556,-0.603333333,-0.756667,5
Elf on the Shelf,-0.04,-0.718333333,-0.863334,1
Pool Cue,-0.334,0,0,9
Tire Repair Kit,-0.223,-0.948333333,-0.076668,6
Silly Putty,-0.112,-0.063333333,-0.183335,1
Nike,-0.123,-0.178333333,0,5
```

Comment: Please see [mcve].

Comment: What are the values that you are trying to turn into float? Make sure that it is a number or floating point number just in a string format. Double check by printing it out by each key

Comment: Just to reinforce what kaya3 said: to be complete, your code would have to include all imports/definitions, and we'd need to see an example csv file. We should be able to run your code and get the same error you are.

Comment: Your first column (i.e., `Item`) is a column of strings. You cannot convert it into float.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the dictionary(items) u have used to iterate the last for loop

{***'Item': ['Guitar Hero', 'iPhone 7', 'iPhone SE', 'Star Wars', 'Markers', 'Avengers', 'Elf on the Shelf', 'Pool Cue', 'Tire Repair Kit', 'Silly Putty', 'Nike']***, 'C1': ['-0.1111', '-0.1', '-0.889', '-0.0778', '-0.667', '-0.556', '-0.04', '-0.334', '-0.223', '-0.112', '-0.123'], 'C2': ['0', '-0.2', '-0.23', '-0.373333333', '-0.488333333', '-0.603333333', '-0.718333333', '0', '-0.948333333', '-0.063333333', '-0.178333333'], 'C3': ['-0.2', '-0.33333', '-0.5', '-0.5', '-0.65', '-0.756667', '-0.863334', '0', '-0.076668', '-0.183335', '0'], 'Constant': ['10', '3', '2', '4', '3', '5', '1', '9', '6', '1', '']}

In the first key("Item") in the dictionary, which has a list of strings as its value. So I have added a if-continue statement, which skips to the next iteration of the loop if the key is "Item".

```
import csv

file = open('Items.csv')
reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
items = dict()
headersRead = False
headers = []

for row in reader:
    if headersRead == False:
        for i in range(len(row)):
            items[row[i]] = []
            print(row[i])

        headers = row
        print(headers)
        headersRead = True

    else:
        for i in range(len(row)):
            items[headers[i]].append(row[i])

for key in items:
    if key == 'Item':
        continue
    c1 = float(items[key][0])
    c2 = float(items[key][1])
    c3 = float(items[key][2])
    constant = float(items[key][3])

file.close()
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't add images for explanation as this is my first answer on Stack overflow.

Comment: If the images would be [of code or text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question), that's frowned upon anyway. But you can add comments or copy and paste example output (and code-format it).